# .net printing using templates

Tags: .net, templates, printing

I'm currently printing in .NET using the PrintDocument class, and it's allright, but the output is rather hard coded. Instead, I'd like to give my users a way to setup something like a template document, with static and dynamic fields. Then my code would keep the static fields (images, fixed text, etc) and fill in the dynamic ones.

What are my options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's blatant advertising, but I suggest using [List & Label](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/report-generator-List-Label).

Disclaimer: I just like that product, I am not affiliated with them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the requirement, ie if you need to print reports I would look at the various reporting tools avalable (eg Telerik / Active Reports)

If you want to produce page based templating for print, I would look at the various PDF generation libraries available as ultimately PDF format is what you should be aiming for.
(eg: iTextSharp, TallComponents, many others)